# Найти конечные координаты линии Line

Tags: c#, wpf

Подскажите как найти конечные координаты линии после поворота.

```
RotateTransform rotateTransform1 = new RotateTransform(60);
Line x = new Line();
x.X1 = 250;
x.Y1 = 250;
x.X2 = 300;
x.Y2 = 250;
x.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
x.StrokeThickness = 2;
rotateTransform1.CenterX = 250;
rotateTransform1.CenterY = 250;
x.RenderTransform = rotateTransform1;
pic_canvas.Children.Add(x);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Возьмите исходные координаты точки
var point = new Point(x.X2, x.Y2);
// Получите объект трансформации
//  здесь может быть любая трансформация, в том числе и смешанная,
//  объединяющая вращение, смещение, масштабирование
var transfrorm = x.RenderTransform;
// Трансформируйте исходную точку с помощью этой трансформации
var realPoint = transfrorm.Transform(point);
```

Answer (score 0):

Если точка `(xold, yold)` поворачивается вокруг центра на угол `Theta`, то новые координаты:

```
xnew = centerx + (xold - centerx) * Cos(Theta) - (yold - centery) * Sin(Theta)
ynew = centery + (xold - centerx) * Sin(Theta) + (yold - centery) * Cos(Theta)
```

Подозреваю, что того же можно добиться с использованием метода `Transform(Point)`